# What's the cnt column in the jmh results?

Tags: jmh

In my jmh class, I'm using

```
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.SampleTime)
@Measurement(iterations = 10)
@Threads(value = 10)
```

at the class level.

And in the results, for the `cnt` column, I see 132, for one method and 155 for another. I was assuming `cnt` might mean number of executions but those numbers don't match what I'm expecting.

Shouldn't number of executions be 10 (threads) * 10 (iterations) = 100?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Frankly, I do not know how `cnt` is calculated when benchmark mode is `Mode.SampleTime`, but I want to clarify a couple of things.

First of all, benchmarking with JMH is concurrent in nature. The `@Threads` annotation specifies that ten threads should be allocated to run your benchmark (default is 4). If you do not specify `@Threads`, it will allocate only one thread for benchmarking.

Secondly, if you change your mode to `Mode.Throughput` and add `@Fork(value = 5)` annotation, you will see `cnt` column with value 50. Because your benchmark will be executed in 5 forks and each fork will have 10 iterations. Simply, `cnt` is `forkNumber * measurementIterations` for this case.

Finally, this calculation changes when mode is `Mode.SampleTime` or when you use `@Param` annotation (`cnt = numOfParams * forkNumber * measurementIterations`). For example, if you run different benchmark with same annotations (`Mode.SampleTime`), you'll see different numbers on `cnt` column.

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

Your premise:

`10 (threads) * 10 (iterations) = 100 = number of executions`

Is incorrect.

The benchmark method will be run repeatedly for 10 measurement iterations, each one a second long, from 10 threads. If the method takes exactly 1 second then the number of executions will match. The reported `cnt` is the number of execution **samples** collected. The `sample` mode does not time each and every execution of the method necessarily. There's a heuristic in place to make it back off if the time taken by the method is very low.